# Image can't be loaded in ListView in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to show a list of images in my UWP Xamarin project.

I don't want to use ImageCell.

That's a sample code from Xamarin Forum.

But I can't complete this code to run successfully.

Here is my code.

```
<ListView  x:Name="listView">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
            Orientation="Vertical">
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding image}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding title}"
                TextColor="#f35e20" />
                <Label Text="{Binding subtitle}"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                TextColor="#503026" />
              </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

public class ImageItem {
string title;
ImageSource image;
string subtitle;
}
ImageItem a= new ImageItem();
a.title = "XXX";
a.image = ImageSource.FromFile(String.Format("{0}{1}.png", Device.OnPlatform("Icons/", "", "Assets/"), "noimage"));
a.subtitle = "XXX";
list.Add(a);
listview.itemsSource = list;
```

I have noimage.png in Assets folder of UWP Xamarin Project.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need `ImageItem` to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface if you want to use bindings. Can you try setting up the class ImageItem like so:

```
public class ImageItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string _title;
    public string title
    {
        get 
        { 
           return _title;
        }
        set
        {
           if (_title != value)
               _title = value;
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("title"));
           }
        }
    }

    ImageSource _image;
    public string image
    {
        get 
        { 
           return _image;
        }
        set
        {
           if (_image != value)
               _image = value;
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("image"));
           }
        }
    }

    string _subtitle;
    public string subtitle
    {
        get 
        { 
           return _subtitle;
        }
        set
        {
           if (_subtitle != value)
               _subtitle = value;
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("subtitle"));
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same.
It displays title and subtitle but not only image.

Comment: Then perhaps it is this line: `ImageSource.FromFile(String.Format("{0}{1}.png", Device.OnPlatform("Icons/", "", "Assets/"), "noimage"));`. As long as the images are where they are supposed to be in the platform project, then you should only have to pass the filename, so perhaps try `ImageSource.FromFile("noimage.png"));`.